# Is this ( using _util functions) an example of clean way for error checking in c?

Tags: c, error-handling

I saw a friend of mine is creating new .c and .h files that contains normalfunctionname_utils() functions. For instance in a project that requires sem_getvalue() for multiple times, error checking takes too much space and it doesn't look that good. i.e:

```
if(sem_getvalue(sem, &val) == -1){
    perror("sem_getvalue:");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

instead of doing this multiple times, is writing a function that does this job and returning value better? i.e:

```
void sem_getvalue_util(sem_t *sem, int *val){
    if(sem_getvalue(sem, val) == -1){
        perror("sem_getvalue:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a perfectly fine error handling strategy. Its benefit is that you get more elegant code, and for small programs it clearly outweighs the drawbacks.

A drawback is that it bakes a specific error handling strategy (exit on error) into the low-level utility functions, so it becomes harder to do something else on error, such as propagate the error to the caller. Another drawback is that it introduces a non-standard abstraction, so someone reading the code has to look up `sem_getvalue_util` to find out exactly what it does.

Answer (score 2):

This is fine for cases where there's absolutely no way for the program logic to proceed in case there are errors. But isn't helpful if there are recoverable errors that should instead be used and handled appropriately.

Also, in case this resides in some piece of code that is invoked by another *client* code in another process/via some library calls, it wouldn't be a good library code and should instead propagate the error back.

There's also one possible problem. In case there's some resource that required explicit release by the program and isn't cleaned up automatically by the OS, then there could be a resource leak for such resources if allocated before this call. That's a rare case but still is something worth considering.